# Transpose data in Excel

Tags: excel, transpose

My table currently looks like this:

```
1   a   b   c   d   e
2   a               
3   b   d   g   h   
4   a   c           
5   d   e   j
```

My desired format is this:

```
1   a
1   b
1   c
1   d
1   e
2   a
3   b
3   d
3   g
3   h
4   a
4   c
5   d
5   e
5   j
```

Is there a way to make this modification in Microsoft Excel? I have attempted this in Ms Access but there is a column limit (225) which I exceed. In addition, I have attempted to use the TRANSPOSE function in Excel, but this only switches rows to columns. Please provide suggestions on how this transformation might be achieved. Thanks!

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal . Then you will need to filter out the blanks in the second column.

Comment: The difference is that my column names are not what I want transposed. So it's not really the same thing

Comment: Put garbage for the column names the delete that column.